# XFCE4 Open PanelMenu via shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, menu

I want open the XFCE4-Menu via a keyboard shortcut. I tried to map the command `xfce4-popup-menu`, but got the error:

```
Failed to execute child process xfce4-popup-menu
```

Then I tried `xfce4-popup-applicationsmenu`, which opens the application menu, but not the one from the panel, just on the desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the Applications Menu in your panel, otherwise it will appear at your mouse cursor.

Comment: I have the applications-menu in my panel, nevertheless it appears at my mouse cursor! Is there another command I could try?

Comment: I have no idea - I have tried on two distributions and both work as expected. With one exception: on multi-monitor setup, when the mouse cursor is on different display, than the **first** panel with the appmenu applet, the menu appears on the display with mouse cursor as close to the applet (on another display) as possible.

Comment: oh that was the problem if I stay on my MainMonitor it works ^_^ do you know if there´s any workaround or something to get this work on the second Monitor too?

Comment: No, sorry. Nothing except for patching the sources (and sending upstream). Or at least [reporting it as a bug](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/).

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to open the menu using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>. It works for me on Xubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

you should use xfce4-popup-whiskermenu to open menu .
or change the ctrl+escape to super L in keyboard settings and application shortcurts